# open pdf without text with python

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want open a PDF for a Django views but my PDF has not a text and python returns me a blank PDF.
On each page, this is a scan of a page : [link](https://github.com/Hyperion60/HyperAnnales/blob/master/Math%C3%A9matiques/td2-s1-correction.pdf)

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def views_pdf(request, path):
   with open(path) as pdf:
   response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(),content_type='application/pdf')
   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;elec'
   return response
```

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError

Exception Value: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 373: character maps to < undefined >

Unicode error hint

The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: � ��`����

How to say at Python that is not a text but a picture ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Python 3 opens files in *text mode*, that is, it tries to interpret the contents of a file as text. This is what causes the exception that you see.

Since a PDF file is (generally) a binary file, try opening the file in binary mode. In that case, `read()` will return a `bytes` object.

Here's an example (in IPython). First, opening as text:

```
In [1]: with open('2377_001.pdf') as pdf:
   ...:     data = pdf.read()
   ...:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d807b6ccea6e> in <module>()
      1 with open('2377_001.pdf') as pdf:
----> 2     data = pdf.read()
      3 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    319         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    320         data = self.buffer + input
--> 321         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    322         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    323         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10: invalid continuation byte
```

Next, reading the same file in binary mode:

```
In [2]: with open('2377_001.pdf', 'rb') as pdf:
   ...:     data = pdf.read()
   ...: 
In [3]: type(data)
Out[3]: bytes

In [4]: len(data)
Out[4]: 45659

In [5]: data[:10]
Out[5]: b'%PDF-1.4\n%'
```

That solves the first part, how to read the data.

The second part is how to pass it to a `HttpResponse`. According to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse):

> "Typical usage is to pass the contents of the page, as a string, to the `HttpResponse` constructor"

So passing `bytes` might or might not work (I don't have Django installed to test). The [Django book](https://djangobook.com/request-response-objects/) says:

> "`content` should be an iterator or a string."

I found the following gist to write binary data:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def django_file_download_view(request):
    filepath = '/path/to/file.xlsx'
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as fp:  # Small fix to read as binary.
        data = fp.read()
    filename = 'some-filename.xlsx'
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype="application/ms-excel")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename # force browser to download file
    response.write(data)
return response
```

Comment: My approach was wrong. My PDF must be seen as an attachment and not a text file.
I used an extra package : "Sendfile".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the file you are trying to using isn't using the correct type of encoding. You can easily find the encoding of your pdf in most pdf viewers like adobe acrobat (in properties). Once you've found out what encoding it's using you can give it to Python like so:

Replace

```
with open(path) as pdf:
```

with :

```
with open(path, encoding="whatever encoding your pdf is in") as pdf:
```

Try `Latin-1` encoding this often works

Comment: Opening a file in binary mode with an encoding raises an exception: `ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument`.